# Project WARNING: *.xcassets in QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA is deprecated. Use QMAKE_ASSET_CATALOGS instead

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

I'm trying to build a Qt Quick app for ios and I'm getting this compile error:

> Project WARNING: *.xcassets in QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA is deprecated. Use QMAKE_ASSET_CATALOGS instead.

I'm following the instructions here:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/platform-notes-ios.html

I've got this in my deployment.pri file:

```
ios {
    assets_catalogs.files = $$files($$PWD/ios/*.xcassets)
    QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA += assets_catalogs
}
```

If I swap out `QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA` for `QMAKE_ASSET_CATALOGS` I get an ios build error:

> :-1: error: Xcodebuild failed.

`QMAKE_ASSET_CATALOGS` also doesn't highlight in Qt Creator. I assume it's because the variable doesn't exist but I'm not sure. I've tried Qt v5.8 and v5.9.2 with no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no more "files" property :

```
QMAKE_ASSET_CATALOGS = $$PWD/ios/Images.xcassets
```

You may need to specify the prefix of the set :

```
QMAKE_ASSET_CATALOGS_APP_ICON = "AppIcon"
```

For me it doesn't work when run from Qt, I have to run from xcode.

*Credits : https://appbus.wordpress.com/2017/10/06/ios-11-and-xcode-9-in-qt-5-9-x-projects/*

Comment: Sorry about taking so long to reply, but this worked perfectly. Thanks!